# Installing Ubuntu onto latest Version of Chrome OS

Tags: chromebook, google

I am using Crouton script to install Gnome Desktop, as that desktop environment is easy for me to work with, as I am completely blind and thus rely on ORCA screen reader to navigate. However, upon installing gnome desktop, I end up with the outdated Xenial environment, which is no longer supported.

Here is my step-by-step walkthrough of how I install Gnome Desktop using Crouton:

1. Enable Developer Mode
2. Download Crouton
3. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
4. Type `shell` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Type:

   ```
   sudo install -Dt /usr/local/bin -m 755 ~/Downloads/crouton
   ```

   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Type:

   ```
   sudo crouton -t gnome-desktop
   ```

   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
7. Wait for the installer to complete
8. Type a username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
9. Type a password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
10. Retype the password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

At this point, you can start Gnome by typing:

```
sudo startgnome
```

Exactly how do I install the latest version of Ubuntu using Crouton without getting Xenial every time I install Gnome Desktop?

Comment: Crouton only supports the outdated Ubuntu 16.04. Check out this answer for full installation https://askubuntu.com/a/1469237/124466

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on Chromebook (Google Pixelbook 2017)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468964/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook-google-pixelbook-2017)

Answer (score 0):

This link explains how to choose your version of Ubuntu.

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/12/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-any.html

After Step 5 from your instructions above and before Step 6, enter:

crouton -r list

for a list of the different distributions. Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa is the latest version that I think is cureently (08/22) available. To install Ubuntu 20.04 with a Unity desktop for example, you would then enter:

sudo crouton -e -r focal -t extension,keyboard,audio,unity

I am not sure you can get Ubuntu 22.04 using the crouton method currently, but I could be wrong.

Cheers!

Comment: I get this on step 6?
sed: can't read common/cras_messages.h: No such file or directory then it fails. any idea why?